# LLDB sometimes displays vector data and other times does not

Tags: c++, xcode, vector, xcode9, lldb

In most cases when debugging, if I have a vector (in Xcode 9), I am shown a list of indices representing the values in the vector.

**Desired**
[image]

Other times, I get this unhelpful representation:

**Undesired**
[image]

I am unable to figure out what conditions cause LLDB to display vectors in the undesirable way.

**Question**
What is causing the undesired behavior? Can it be fixed without re-writing the code? Is this a bug in LLDB?

Here is a short code example that reproduces the undesired behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> createVector()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    return v;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    const auto& v = createVector();
    std::cout << v.front() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to the Xcode project:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=21020556485232357417

Comment: The only obvious difference between the two is that one is a completely STL type -- a vector of unique pointers to ints. The second involves a custom or third-party library type. Perhaps if XCode doesn't know how to parse the "Imxr::MxrLinked[List?]" type, it gives up parsing the unique ptr / vector alltogether?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear that this is not the issue. Let me know if the edit helped.

Comment: What optimisations do you compile with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in how the std::vector data summary & formatters work for reference variables.  Note that in the `expr v` the expression parser actually considers v to be a straight vector, not a reference to a vector...  That's why that printing works.

Comment: Is there an open bug report of this?  If so, a link would complete the answer.

Comment: There's a bug in the Apple Bug Reporter system, but that is only visible externally to whoever filed the bug.  I didn't find an equivalent bug in the http://llvm.org/bugs tracker.  It would be worth adding one in case somebody externally has the time to fix it before we get to it.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I add my comment here in the answers, since Stack Overflow comments do not support formatting.

It is definitely the lldb's issue. Your pictures do not contain the full v description:

```
v = (const std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &) size=1
```

The `size=1` is incorrect.
Besides the print command in the lldb console prints `v` correctly:

```
(lldb) p v
(const std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) $1 = size=3 {
  [0] = 1
  [1] = 2
  [2] = 3
}
```

It seems Xcode uses the lldb `frame var` command to display variables. This displays exactly the same output that is displayed by Xcode:

```
(lldb) frame variable -T
(int) argc = 1
(const char **) argv = 0x00007fff5fbff710
(const std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > &) v = size=1: {
  (std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >) std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > = {
    (std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::pointer) __begin_ = 0x000000010103fa40
    (std::__1::__vector_base<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::pointer) __end_ = 0x000000010103fa4c
    (std::__1::__compressed_pair<int *, std::__1::allocator<int> >) __end_cap_ = {
      (std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<int *, std::__1::allocator<int>, 2>) std::__1::__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<int *, std::__1::allocator<int>, 2> = {
        (int *) __first_ = 0x000000010103fa4c
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think the issue comes from the fact that the variable `v` was initially created and initialised in another stack frame, thus some information about the vector is unknown in the lower stack frame when the initial vector was passed as a result of the function call.